# Display only the last four digit number from a String

Tags: javascript, logic

Need to show only the last four digit of the credit card number from a message using javascript.

Ex:

```
var = "CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
CARD SWIPED
1111222233334444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
GIFT CARD SWIPED
1111222233334444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
GIFT CARD SWIPED
1111222233334444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
CARD SWIPED
1111222233334444"
```

Need the Expected output as

```
"GIFT CARD SWIPED
4444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
CARD SWIPED
4444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
CARD SWIPED
4444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
CARD SWIPED
4444
CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING
CARD SWIPED
4444"
```

Any help in this regards, will be appreciated.

Comment: Uhm, but the numbers are not the only difference in there. Do you want/have to do something else as well?

Comment: need the show only the last four number with that string as shown in the expected output

Comment: @Acube "GIFT" should be added before the text ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much in Javascript, Having java background I could think only this logic.

```
var str = "CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING GIFT CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING GIFT CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444"; 
var res = str.match(/[0-9]+/g);

for (var i=0; i<res.length ; i++){
  var lastFourStr = res[i].substring(res[i].length-4, res[i].length);
  str =  str.replace(res[i], lastFourStr);
}
console.log(str);
```

Created a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4ivm4DvESoUABTkdahh?p=preview) link for the same

I feel there will be a better way than this

> Update: you can have this to match exactly 16 digit  `var res = str.match(/\b\d{16}\b/g);`

Update on the pattern

> Update II : `var regex = str.match(/\b(\d{4}( \d{4}){3})\b/g)` This pattern will verify the number with space we can merge this with your existing pattern  `var res = str.match(/(\b\d{16}\b|\b(\d{4}( \d{4}){3})\b)/g);`

Comment: this is working for 16 digit number and all the non 16 digit continuous number also. this should work for only the 16 digit number and other continuous numbers should be ignored. for Example Now its showing 112234   also like this 2234 (this should be like this 112234).

Comment: @Acube Please find the update section in my answer and Plnkr link will be holding the updated one. Please let me know, whether this resolves or not

Comment: @ Hurix, Thanks a lot. its working fine, but it taking this "Ref. # 24445005206100438283410......." to "Ref. # 00438283410....... ". Why not showing the full number. Other than this everything is fine.

Comment: @Acube Sorry for that, Added word boundary to my regex, please refer the update section. I hope it wil be working now

Comment: that worked fine, and while testing i found another issue its not working for the below message "CARD SWIPED 1111 2222 3333 4444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING"

Comment: thanks a lot for your code, is this not possible to make it work for this message "CARD SWIPED 1111 2222 3333 4444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING 1111 2222 3333 4444"

Comment: @Acube Different regex pattern should be followed to achieve that and I am not good at regex . Anyhow I tried this and giving you a sample code http://plnkr.co/edit/U4ivm4DvESoUABTkdahh?p=preview. I hope your question is resolved (Please mark this as an answer ) and please make another question for regex and tag it as regex

Comment: can you paste your final code here, i am sorry couldn't find it that link

Comment: @Acube Please find it in the update. You can get the code in my plnkr link also, it is available in script.js file

Comment: if i type this alone this way "1111 2222 3333 4444"  or "www
1111 2222 3333 4444" or "www
1111 2222 3333 4444 www"  its not working. Please give a solution for this too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84777/discussion-between-hurix-and-acube).

Comment: @Acube Please come to the chat room. The above pattern works please refer the script.js file

Answer (score 0):

If the number would be any where in var. then this code can find the value--

```
         function getDigit(){

              var ex= "CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER 
NOT RESPONDING CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING GIFT CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT   SERVER NOT RESPONDING GIFT CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444 CREDIT SERVER NOT RESPONDING CARD SWIPED 1111222233334444";

            var store=ex.split(" ");

                var lastFour="";

                for (var i in store) {
                    var temp=store[i];

                    var sd=parseInt(temp);
                    sd=sd+"";
                    if($.isNumeric(sd) )
                        {
                        lastFour=sd.substring((sd.length-4),sd.length);
                        }
                }                   
                alert(lastFour);}
```